# How to bypass Mac permission to run .command or .sh file

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, command

I have to make a click to run  .command/ shell script (.sh) for my users on mac.

I did manage to make .sh work=> to do that I have to type these in to terminal at that folder.

```
chmod a+x myFile.sh
```

But none of my users are technical. So they cant type on terminal.

I tried creating .command file. But this also needs special permission to execute.
And that permission cant be given via right click- info - permissions.
This permission can only given by terminal code.Thx to stpd mac security policies.

Also  creating .app won't work , because that way also needs a permission code on terminal.

Is there any hero to help me solve this problem

Edit 1: Forgot to mention that app I am trying to distribute is Java app, .jar. I need to run sh to run specific commands to run myapp.jar.

Comment: You  could try to set the permissions with the ProcesBuilder. For further info have a look on my blog post: https://thilosdevblog.wordpress.com/2022/09/18/how-to-properly-handle-the-output-of-the-processbuilder/

Comment: You could perform the equivalent of `chmod a+x` in your Java program by using `myFile.setExecutable(true)` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setExecutable(boolean)

Comment: Do you need the solution to be Java-specific? Otherwise, the Automator app can generate you an app that runs a shell script

Comment: Why is this tagged Java?

Comment: Make your script executable and then distribute it inside a .tar file. Alternatively, wrap it inside an .app and sign and notarize it with an Apple Developer ID.

Comment: @Lasse I'dont. Can I make an automator work on other computers??

Comment: @TheNextman Hi, I forgot to mention that , I am trying to distribute a java app.

Comment: @TheNextman I will try it and let people here to know if it works.

Comment: `sh myFile.sh`.  This way the executable is `sh` a system command, and your script can remain not +x.